# Excel opening with c# gets error at server

Tags: c#, excel

i have a console app. at server computer. this console is listening every 5 minutes a one file which has got excell files. When one of them from this excel files is opening i get a error like this :

```
Office has detected a problem with this file. To help protect your computer this
 file cannot be opened.
```

i get this error this line,

```
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(directory, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
```

i think this excel file will be destroyed but when i try this my local it works clearly What can i do for this  situation ?

Comment: Look at the file yourself in windows explorer, it's probably disabled because it was downloaded from a remote location and has a flag set when you right-click and open the properties window

Comment: which propery must be changed ? yes i have download from remote location

Comment: see http://superuser.com/questions/590787/what-does-it-mean-when-a-file-is-blocked-in-windows  is this the case with your excel files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file poses a security risk. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973736. MS recommends moving the file to a trusted location on the server.

To remedy in code, take a look at [C# Excel 2010 Workbook Open error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970265/c-sharp-excel-2010-workbook-open-error).

Comment: hi i examine this solution but i am using office 2003. this code not valid  in 2003.  excelApp.FileValidation = MsoFileValidationMode.msoFileValidationSkip; is there any other solution to do this in 2003

Comment: i have added trusted location at my server. and it's running. Thank you to much @rcJames

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem to use below solution.

[image]