# Run-time error upon opening excel file

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to open excel files in a `button_click` event. I don't encounter any errors with the first four excel files i opened, but as my macro open the fifth one, it stops and shows this run-time error:

```
Run-time error '-2147021892 (80070bbc)':

office has detected a problem with this file. 
To help protect your computer this file cannot be opened.
```

Here's my code for opening excel files:

```
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=fileName, UpdateLinks:=True)
```

Comment: Try opening it manually to get a clue of what is different on that file. There may be some unreadable items or the file may be corrupt.

Comment: @pnuts type is Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet (.xls) and yes, all the files have the same type and same location. I tried putting the problem file first but it doesn't make any difference. The run-time error still show.

Comment: as @l42 suggested, can you open the file manually? And do you get the same message? If yes, then your file is corrupt. Try recreating the file.

Comment: @SiddharthRout i can open the file manually but it is automatically in a protected view because of the same error.

Comment: That means your file is corrupt. Try re-creating the file

Comment: I think the link posted as answer on the last line will solve your problem. I'm talking about [THIS LINK](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922850), the RESOLUTION part which has something to do with file blocking.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thanks! i recreated the file.

Comment: @L42 i did what was written in that link but it didn't solve my problem. I recreated the file instead. but thanks for the response though :)

Comment: No worries. glad you solved your problem :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Possible resolutions**

[Microsoft Support - Error message in Office when a file is blocked by registry policy settings](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922850) gives several mechanisms for how to possibly bypass this error if you trust the document content.

Some Key Notes:

> **For Excel 2010 or 2013**
>
> Change the File Block settings to disable the restriction of certain file types through File -> Options -> Trust Center -> Trust Settings
>
> **For Excel 2003 or 2007**
>
> You have to change the value of the FileOpenBlock registry subkey to disable the restriction of certain file types. This is located at
>
> For Excel 2007:
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Excel\Security\FileOpenBlock
>
> For Excel 2003:
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Excel\Security\FileOpenBlock
>
> Subkeys should be as follows:
>
> [image: FileOpenBlock registry subkeys]

**Why this is occurring**

From [Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973736):

> SYMPTOMS
>
> You perform one of the following actions in a Microsoft Office 2010 application:
>
> •Open an embedded object
>
> •Perform a mail merge
>
> •Open a file from a viewer
>
> In this situation, you receive the following error message:
>
> Office has detected a problem with this file. To help protect your computer this file cannot be opened.
>
> CAUSE
>
> This problem occurs because Office File Validation detects a problem
>   with the file that may pose a security risk. You receive the error
>   message for a malicious file or for a damaged file.

It appears that Office is detecting something possibly malicious with the file, such as a virus or other malware, or it's just possible that the file is corrupted. If you trust this document, proceed with opening it. Otherwise be extremely cautious to avoid an malware infection of some type.

Comment: Oh, so the OP could perhaps be opening an XLSM file? Excel is quite distrusting of files with macros enabled.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. File was corrupted and VBA open threw that error. As a possible solution I found this (faname is a string with the path):

```
Workbooks.Open FileName:= fname, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True, _
   IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True, Password:="", Editable:=FALSE, _
   CorruptLoad:= xlExtractData
```

The important part is "CorruptLoad:= xlExtractData", that makes it possible to load the data from corrupted files without throwing this error. The other things are just there to prevent the file from doing something... together with

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

Just as a precaution before opening the file... if you do that do not forget to undo it before your Macro finishes like (these are my standard settings, use your own! you may find them out using Debug.Print in the Immediate Window):

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlNormal
Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow
```

Be careful what your security settings actually are and do not blindly copy these changes of settings...
Also best to catch errors ("On Error ...") and terminate with resetting your previous settings.

Comment: set CorruptLoad:= xlExtractData is ok. and have other solution, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970265/c-sharp-excel-2010-workbook-open-error, set msoFileValidationSkip on excel app

Answer (score 2):

I tried the line of code above with my "corrupted" file.
The result was disasterous, (but original was backed up).
All Excel worksheets (13) now have text, and
All approx 93 pages of VBA code are gone.  Styles=17: File size is <2000kb.

One cell with a changed cell format causes the infamous M/S error text.
I don't think this is corrupt, but it may be too much programming for Excel(s).

Comment: I tried the same solution as the above and it forced the script to read in a bad file and the data becomes garbage. Not really sure when that corruptload option would come in handy, if the data it retrieves is not usable.

Comment: If you try to restore a file for whatever reason, do not overwrite the original file, so you can still try other methods. If the file is corrupted, there is a high possibility that data is lost. And about the x pages of VBA code: I usually make back ups of my VBA code in a text editor and save it with the ending ".vb", so my editor (notepad++) picks up the syntax highlight correctly... Often I also just write the code directly there and then copy it in to the Excel at the end for debugging. I lost work before due to corrupted Excel files, so I always work with back ups.

Comment: @user2025696: You may need that code if you want to open a large number of files and extract data from them, if possible. You do not want to your Macro to stop in between for a corruped file and still get out data, if possible. Make some sanity checks, as well to prevent loading garbage and you can efficiently extract data from hundreds or more files with one run of a macro.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the file seems to downloaded/copied from external source, like the internet.
The below page discussed how to "unblock" such files programatically via VBA.
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-msoffice_custom/how-to-unblock-file-using-vba/bed82938-6a57-403c-afcf-fa76a26a1ac6

See Andreas Killer's solution. he mentioned that what you clear is not a file attribute, you remove the alternate data stream "Zone.Identifier" from the file.
And gives the following links:-
A wiki link ... en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Alternate_data_streams_.28ADS.29
http://vb.mvps.org/samples/Streams/

Above 2nd link to Karl E. Peterson's website provides a Streams.zip file, which contains CStreams class that needs to be imported into your project and use the KillStream function.

```
Sub Test()
  Dim C As New CStreams
  Dim i As Integer
With C
  .FileName = "C:\test.txt"
  For i = 1 To .Count - 1
    Debug.Print .KillStream(i)
  Next
End With
End Sub
```

-Credit to Andreas Killer

Hope this helps.