# VBA Run-time error '-2147021892 (80070bbc)'

Tags: excel, vba

When I try to run my VBA

```vb
Workbooks.Open Directory1
```

Excel gives me the following error:

[image]

I have these settings in Excel:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check "File Block Settings" in the Trust Center. See [Error message in Office when a file is blocked by registry policy settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/settings/file-blocked-in-office)

Comment: Did you yourself choose those settings that make your computer open to every last bit of Office malware, or did you *end up* with them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Run-time error upon opening excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777899/run-time-error-upon-opening-excel-file)

Comment: @GSerg reminds me of another SO member who mentioned those settings were the company's policy... I think management *wanted* their systems hijacked and plundered

Comment: Apparently it works with this code,

Application.ProtectedViewWindows.Open Filename:=Directory1
Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Edit

,but it's slower

Comment: I chose the setting myself

Comment: *"I chose the setting myself"* Worst idea, highly recommended to go back (at least) to default settings. • Didn't you see the *"Not recommended, dangerous"* warning behind the macro setting? • Which filetype is `Directory1`? and what are your  "File Block Settings" in the Trust Center?

Comment: thank you guys. I just had to unticked some options in "File Block Settings". I have changed back to the default setting.